# Accessing Google Translate via C#

Tags: c#, google-translate

First of all: I intend to write a c# application that enables the user to instantly translate textboxes in JRPGs and Visual Novels from Japanese to English or any other language. The later code will include methods to detect text boxes, mostly inspired by car licence plate recognition, but that's far in the future. So far, I'm at the beginning stages, I'm using IronOCR for the OCR and send the Japanese character string to google translate via the URL. But this causes a temporary ban for obvious reasons. I want to prevent that ban or find a more secure and safe way to use google translate in my use case. Here the relevant code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using IronOcr;
using IronOcr.Languages;



namespace OCRTranslate
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Bitmap imgsource = new Bitmap(@"C:\temp\Unbenannt.png");
            var Ocr = new AdvancedOcr()
            {
                Language = IronOcr.Languages.Japanese.OcrLanguagePack,
            };
            var Resulta = Ocr.Read(@"C:\temp\Unbenannt.png");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\Unbenanntiron.txt", TranslateGoogle());

            string TranslateGoogle()
            {
                string html = null;
                string url = string.Format(@"http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=j&text={0}&h1=en&sl=ja&tl=en", Resulta);
                System.Net.WebClient web = new System.Net.WebClient();
                web.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0");
                web.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "UTF-8");
                web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                html = web.DownloadString(url);
                return html;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works pretty flawlessly, to my surprise the Japanese text from the image was returned translated, but even one try causes the temporary ban... Any suggestion or even alternative to google translate is welcome.

Edit: Using that URL in my Firefox obviously doesn't cause a ban. Technically i could open the URL via the browser from the c# application. The browser outputs a textfile using the URL... So is it somehow possible to catch the texfile via c#?

Another Idea: Can i send a URL to an already open Firefox window?

Comment: What if the user is not connected to the internet tho ? That's a pretty good idea, sad that it won't work if you don't have any access to google.

Comment: Well, i'm still looking for an offline solution, but the google translate solution is the most solid one. The translations generated by this machine translator are the best translation attempts from Japanese I've come across so far.

Answer (score 3):

The publicly available Google Translate web site is designed for use by human operators through a browser. It's not an API designed for developers.

Use the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) instead.

This allows you to choose the pricing/quota combination that applies to your requirements. In addition, there are [various nuget Packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google+translate) readily available for connecting a C# application to the Google Translation API.

Comment: This is no commercial project. So far it's more testing my idea. It's basically a hobby thing, so i don't intend to buy a licence for something i don't know i'll be able to accomplish. I'm looking for a free of charge solution here... At least for now.

Comment: @DesMondesBlut: Then you will have to look for an alternative to Google. The [Microsoft Translation API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/) has a free tier, for example, for a maximum of 2.000.000 characters per month.

Comment: What about using google translate remotely without any API?

Comment: @wEight: That might be a violation of their TOS, so double-check those before trying it.

Comment: I'm not trying anything before proper research. :)